# internationalization problem when I switch Languages

Tags: dart, internationalization, flutter

I have a little bug with the flutter internationalization.
I used `formTextFields` and, when the validate is not satisfied, they display some hints like "`Insert username`" or "`insert password`". Now, the problem that I have, when I switch language, while I'm in the app, is that these Strings don't change Instantaneously, but they will change only after I press again the login button (and use so the validate function). Everything else changes, but those hint don't.

Here's my locales file where I set the internationalization:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:mobile/l10n/messages_all.dart';

class AppLocalizations {

  static Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    final String name =
        locale.countryCode.isEmpty ? locale.languageCode : locale.toString();


    final String localeName = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(name);


    return initializeMessages(localeName).then((bool _) {
      Intl.defaultLocale = localeName;
      return AppLocalizations();
    });
  }


  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }



  String get loginText {
    return Intl.message('Login',
        //name should be the same as the actual variable name because this
        //will be the key to associate these values
        name: 'loginText',
        //The description is optional
        desc: "if you see the world 'login', call this one!");
  }

  String get usernameText{
    return Intl.message('Username',
    name: 'usernameText',
    );
  }


  String get passwordText{
    return Intl.message('Password',
    name: 'passwordText'
    );
  }


  String get insertUsernameText{
    return Intl.message('Insert username',
        name: 'insertUsernameText'
    );

  }

  String get insertPasswordText{
    return Intl.message('Insert password',
        name: 'insertPasswordText'
    );
  }


}


class AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const AppLocalizationsDelegate();


  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    // TODO: implement isSupported
    return ['en', 'de', 'ja'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  //calls app locations method created up top
  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return AppLocalizations.load(locale);
  }


  @override
  shouldReload(AppLocalizationsDelegate old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And here's the `TextFormField` code

```
TextFormField( decoration: _fieldDecoration(AppLocalizations.of(context).passwordText, Icons.lock),
                    onSaved: (val) {
                      _password = val;
                    },
                    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? AppLocalizations.of(context).insertPasswordText : null,
                  ),
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of the form fields as well.

Comment: form fields code added!

Comment: Do you create the `TextFormField` inside `build` or do you hold it in a variable that is reused if build is called multiple times?

Comment: It's inside the build

Comment: Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

you should call `validate` method from `FormState` in `build` method by using key to refresh the language of validation messages

create global key

```
GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey=GlobalKey<FormState> ();
```

and assign key to `Form` Widget

```
  Form(
    key: _formKey,
    ..
)
```

and call validate form method in build method

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(!isvalidTextFields)
      if(_formKey.currentState!=null)
      _formKey.currentState.validate();
       ..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> This AppLocalizations Code Working Fine in My App..do some changes As per Code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:COMO/constants/string_constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show SynchronousFuture;

class AppLocalizations {
  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  final Locale locale;

  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  static Map<String, Map<String, String>> _localizedValues = {
    'en': {
      // Section contains SignIn Strings ;
      'Sign in': 'Sign in',
      'Email Address': 'Email Address',
      'Password': 'Password',
      'LOGIN': 'LOGIN',
      'Forgot Password?': 'Forgot Password',
      'Sign Up': 'Sign Up',
      'lbSignUpStr': 'Do not have an account?',
      'errorEnterMail': 'Please Enter Email',
      'errorEnterPwd': 'Please Enter Password',
      'errorInvalidPwd': 'Invalid Password',
      'errorInvalidMail': 'Invalid Email',

      // Section contains SignUp Strings ;
      'First Name': 'First Name',
      'Last Name': 'Last Name',
      'phoneNo': 'Phone Number(*)',
      'createAccount': 'CREATE ACCOUNT',
      'signUpAgreementStart': StringConstant.TermsAndConditionStrStart,
      'signUpAgreementEnd': StringConstant.TermsAndConditionStrEnd,
      'errorEnterFname': 'Please Enter First Name',
      'errorEnterLname': 'Please Enter Last Name',
      'errorEnterPhoneNo': "Please Enter Phone Number",

      // Section contains Drawer Strings ;

      'writeToUs': 'Write To Us',
      'comoLocation': 'Como Location',
      'rateTheApp': 'Rate the App',
      'whyComo': 'Why..Como..',
      'serviceRate': 'Service Rate',
      'followUs': 'Follow us on:',


    },
    'ar': {
      'Sign in': 'تسجيل الدخول',
      'Email Address': 'عنوان بريد الكتروني',
      'Password': 'كلمه السر',
      'LOGIN': 'تسجيل الدخول',
      'Forgot Password?': 'هل نسيت كلمة المرور؟',
      'Sign Up': 'سجل',
      'lbSignUpStr': 'لا تملك حساب؟',
      'errorEnterMail': 'الرجاء إدخال البريد الإلكتروني',
      'errorEnterPwd': 'من فضلك أدخل كلمة المرور',
      'errorInvalidPwd': 'رمز مرور خاطئ',
      'errorInvalidMail': 'بريد إلكتروني خاطئ',
      'First Name': 'الاسم الاول',
      'Last Name': 'الكنية',
      'phoneNo': 'رقم الهاتف(*)',
      'createAccount': 'إنشاء حساب',
      'signUpAgreementStart': 'بإنشاء حسابك ، أنت توافق على موقعنا',
      'signUpAgreementEnd': 'البنود و الظروف',
      'errorEnterFname': 'الرجاء إدخال الاسم الأول',
      'errorEnterLname': 'الرجاء إدخال الاسم الأخير',
      'errorEnterPhoneNo': "الرجاء إدخال رقم الهاتف",

      // Section contains Drawer Strings ;

      'writeToUs': 'اكتب لنا ',
      'comoLocation': 'كومو الموقع',
      'rateTheApp': 'قيم التطبيق',
      'whyComo': 'لماذا .. كومو ..',
      'serviceRate': 'معدل خدمة',
      'followUs': 'اتبعنا:',
    },
  };

  // Login UI Localization functions
  String get lbSignIn {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['Sign in'];
  }

  String get errorEnterMail {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['errorEnterMail'];
  }

  String get errorEnterPwd {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['errorEnterPwd'];
  }

  String get errorInvalidPwd {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['errorInvalidPwd'];
  }

  String get errorInvalidMail {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['errorInvalidMail'];
  }

  String get emailAddress {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['Email Address'];
  }

  String get password {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['Password'];
  }

  String get login {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['LOGIN'];
  }

  String get forgotPassword {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['Forgot Password?'];
  }

  String get signUp {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['Sign Up'];
  }

  String get lbSignUpStr {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['lbSignUpStr'];
  }

  // Sign Up UI Localization Function
  String get firstName {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['First Name'];
  }

  String get lastName {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['Last Name'];
  }

  String get phoneNo {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['phoneNo'];
  }

  String get createAccount {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['createAccount'];
  }

  String get signUpAgreementStart {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['signUpAgreementStart'];
  }

  String get signUpAgreementEnd {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['signUpAgreementEnd'];
  }

  String get errorEnterFirstname {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['errorEnterFname'];
  }

  String get errorEnterLastname {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['errorEnterLname'];
  }

  String get errorEnterPhoneNo {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['errorEnterPhoneNo'];
  }

  // Drawer UI Localization Function
  String get writeToUs {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['writeToUs'];
  }
  String get comoLocation {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['comoLocation'];
  }
  String get rateTheApp {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['rateTheApp'];
  }

  String get whyComo {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['whyComo'];
  }
  String get serviceRate {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['serviceRate'];
  }

  String get followUs {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['followUs'];
  }
}
```